# Is there some convenient ORM library framework for c?

Tags: c, database, orm

I use sqlite3 with c language recently. Can anyone tell me some convenient ORM for c? 
Is there necessay to develop a ORM mechanism for my own projects?

Comment: Seems like anyone who would want an ORM is unlikely to be coding in C..

Comment: What do you have in mind given that C is generally missing the Object part of that acronym?

Comment: i have wondered about this too (some kind of library to automate access from c); it would probably map a struct to a row in a table.  please can downvoters/closers explain why?

Comment: I know C is lack of some feature to establish the ORM mechanism. What i expect is just more convenient to access the DB instead of the prototype DB API.

Comment: i started to sketch out what might be possible here - http://isti.bitbucket.org/2012/05/16/orm-for-c.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a need for ORM suggests to me that you have some sort of business / domain object model in mind that you want to map to a database.

If that is the case, then it strikes me that you are trying to write a business application in a language best suited for systems programming (C). You might want to consider whether this is a good architectural strategy.

Furthermore, I don't think ORM is ever likely to be a good fit for a language that:

1. Isn't itself object-oriented
2. Doesn't have much support for meta-programming / reflection which tends to be central to many ORM schemes

Finally, there are plenty of people who believe that ORM is an anti-pattern in any case. ([example](http://seldo.com/weblog/2011/08/11/orm_is_an_antipattern), [example](http://dkalemis.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/the-orm-anti-pattern-and-other-solutions/), [example](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy))

Overall, my suggestion would be to either:

- Avoid ORM altogether if you plan to continue using C
- Switch to a language / platform where ORM is at least well supported and fits the paradigm (most obviously Java)

Comment: Thank u so much. The suggestions are helpful. My original intention is  to avoid repeated manipulate to access the DB. Because i found many repetition code in my project. I wrote some mechanism to do so, but it's so hard to abstract completely. I consider to find ORM first, and there are few.

Answer (score 2):

i wrote [this library](https://bitbucket.org/isti/c-orm/wiki/Home) as an "ORM for C".

example code looks like:

```
typedef struct person {
  int id;
  char *name;
} person;

void find_by_name(isti_db *db, const char *text, person** result) {
  corm_person_select *s;
  corm_person_select_alloc(&s, db);
  s->name(s, "like", text)->_go_one(s, result);  // populate result from the database
  s->_free(s, 0);  // in "real" code, 0 is a chained status value
}
```

unfortunately, it's not in use anywhere (as far as i know) and it includes quite a few ideas that seasoned c programmers might find odd.  but it's not abandoned - i am still interested in the problem and hope to continue work on it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

A brief google search came up with this: http://ales.jikos.cz/smorm/

I have never used it, so don't blame me if it reformats all your hard drives and makes your refrigerator just warm enough to spoil your milk, but it looks like it might be better than nothing if you really don't want to write queries.